# Deriving the formula for the radius of the circle inscribed in an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, triangles

I am trying to derive the formula for the radius of the circle inscribed in an equilateral triangle from scratch.

Given

> $2*n$ = length of a side
>
> $H$ = the altitude of the triangle = $h + a$
>
> $h$ = the long subdivision (from the center of the triangle to a vertex)
>
> $a$ = the short subdivision (from the center of the triangle to a side.  Also the radius of the inscribed circle)

[image: A]

By first deriving the altitude of the triangle

$\displaystyle
\begin{align}
2 n&=\sqrt{H^2+n^2} \\
H&=\sqrt{(2 n)^2-n^2} \\
&=\sqrt{3}\;n \\
\end{align}$

I have gotten to the reduced equation

> $n \sqrt(3) - a = \sqrt(a^2+n^2)$

$\displaystyle
\begin{align}
a+h=\sqrt{3}\;n \\
h=\sqrt{3}\;n-a \\\\
a^2+n^2=h^2 \\
h=\sqrt{a^2+n^2} \\
\end{align}$

Trying to solve for $a$, I know [in advance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle) that $a$ is $1/3$ and $h$ is $2/3$ of $H$, with

> $a = n\sqrt(3)/3$

This is of course the answer I wish to derive.

In fact, plugging the equation given above into a system such as Mathematica will provide the correct answer.  But I can't find out what the steps are, primarily because I know of now way to extract the $a$ term from within the square root term.

Please, no trigonometry.  I know there is a fast derivation involving tangents, etc, but this is more properly an algebra problem - how to solve the equation for $a$.

Comment: Could you try do square both sides?

Comment: It is a bit cleaner if you divide by $n$ and let $b=\frac an$.  Then you have $\sqrt 3 - b = \sqrt{b^2+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square both sides, and you end up with a quadratic equation in $a$.

Comment: In fact it is linear.  The $a^2$'s cancel

Comment: I had done that, but I made a mistake in my FOIL, writing $n^2*3-2a n \sqrt(3) + 2a$ instead of the problem-solving $n^2*3-2a n \sqrt(3) + a^2$.

Comment: The final solution being from 1) my formula to 2) the $a^2+n^2$ = FOIL given above, 3) $2n^2=2a n \sqrt(3)$, 4) $a=n/\sqrt(3)$ (which is equivalent to the _a priori_ answer given in-problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you knew that $H$ is divided in the ratio $2:1$. That means that $h=2a$. So by the Pythagorean Theorem
$$(2a)^2=a^2+n^2.$$
It follows that $3a^2=n^2$ and therefore $a=\frac{n}{\sqrt{3}}$. If you like, then multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{3}$ to get your preferred form.

**Another way:** As you did, use the Pythagorean Theorem to find that $H=\sqrt{3}\, n$. The little triangle you are focused on is *similar* (same angles) to the triangle which is half of the big triangle.  It follows that 
$$\frac{h}{n}=\frac{n}{H}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{3}\,n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},$$
and now the desired result follows. The advantage is that we do not have to prove the $2:1$ property, though in fact it follows easily from the same pair of similar triangles.

Comment: Your first solution won't work because I'm not actually using the 2:1 ratio, it is known to be true but not within the scope of the problem, and I can use it to check the result I get.

Comment: The second solution is intriguing.  It did work, and much more directly than the equation solving.  However, I think your proportion is incorrect:  I get $h/n=2n/H$, from which I derive the correct answer as you show.